# Nested foreign keys (with multiple tables)

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, mysql-workbench

I have three tables:

user: id

folders: id, user_id

words: id, folders_id

(there are more columns in every tables, but they are for this problem irrelevant)

A user contains several folders and each folder contains several words.

So far so good. I interconnected these tables with foreign Keys with the help of MySQL Workbench.

What MySQL-Workbench does for the first connection (folders.user_id -> user.id) is as I expected it. But when I add the second relationship (words.folders_id -> folders.id), It automatically generates an index over two columns: the expected one folders.id but also over the column of the first foreign key folders.user_id

[image: This is the screenshot of MySQL Workbench after having added the second foreign key. Automatically, this one is generated also over the column of the first foreign key: folders.user_id]

I always thought, that duplicate data in a MySQL-Database is not a good solution. But why does MySQL-Workbench propose me to do it this way? The only advantage I can think of is, that I can select the user's id from a word directly without a JOIN. Is this the purpose of this index over two columns?

Thanks for explaining me this phenomenon.

---

I haven't found a solution yet, but when I search in google images for [diagrams of relationships in MySQL Workbench](https://www.google.com/search?q=foreign%20keys%20workbench&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla%3ade%3aofficial&client=firefox-a&um=1&ie=UTF-8&hl=de&tbm=isch&source=og&sa=N&tab=wi&ei=ECDiUKy-L47s9ASz5YDQCg&biw=1536&bih=660&sei=EyDiUKTAFIb28wSK7IHIBg), these nested foreign keys never appear. So I assume they are not necessary and I just keep deleting them when MySQL Workbench creates them.

Comment: Does your `words` table actually have a column called `user_id` as well?

Comment: MySQL Workbench produces me automatically this column words.user_id.  My question is now, why it produces this "doubled data".

Answer (score 0):

why don't you write the query as follows:

```
select user.id from user
inner join folders on folders.user_id=user.id
inner join words on words.folder_id=folders.id
```

Comment: That is exactly how I would have done it. But my question is, why MySQL Workbench proposes me anothet solution.

Comment: is this the way that serve your purpose?

Comment: Yes, that serves my purpose. It's working perfectly, but my question is a different one: Why does MySQL Workbench per default do it another way? Has that way any advantage to the one you have described in your answer?

Comment: I think, MySql itself may organize data efficiently in that way. i don't see any other reasons.